# Is Asia Ortega actually deaf or hearing-impaired?

Tags: character, the-boarding-school-las-cumbres

[Asia Ortega](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2399032/?ref_=tt_cl_t_8) plays a hearing-impaired character in [*The Boarding School: Las Cumbres*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11709206/)

There was an episode where she removes her hearing aids but in real life, is she actually deaf/impaired or is she a regular hearing person?

Comment: I'm struggling a little to understand if you're asking about the actress or the character here. You...seem to be asking both and also conflating actress and character in other sentences.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson  - I choose those two because I had to choose 5 tags that came up and don't know what to  choose.

Comment: The tag isn't necessarily the issue, but it appears that you are asking if the actress who plays the character is also hearing impaired in real life? I edited the Q to reflect that better. But the tag still may need to be changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hearing aids were a prop for her character in the show only. She does not have a hearing impairment in real life.

[translated text]

> Amaia Torres, played by Asia Ortega. She is a popular girl, who came to school **after shooting her father with a shotgun**, an event that led to her having to use earphones as **the shot made her almost completely deaf**. She is engaged to Manuel and immediately fights to understand what happened to him.

[translated text]

> Asia Ortega, the main protagonist, explains how **her character Amaia's disability was a challenge for her**.
>
> "My **character** has a physical difficulty. **She's deaf** and that's been a **challenge for me** and also a gift because she's given me that double-edged sword of being able to have a limitation, but, at the same time, a superpower of lip-reading, for example."
>
> https://www.eltiempo.com/cultura/cine-y-tv/amazon-prime-video-el-internado-las-cumbres-nueva-serie-de-terror-568016

image of her, in the show, with hearing aid:

[image]

Unable to find image of her with hearing aid in real life interviews.

less strong [translated] links:

> With a distinctive feature above the rest of the students - the young woman is deaf - and with a special ability to glimpse spirits and supernatural presences;
>
> https://www-terra-com-mx.translate.goog/entretenimiento/2021/2/21/asia-ortega-la-joven-revelacion-de-el-internado-las-cumbres-que-brilla-con-su-personaje-12182.html

> Amaia goes with fury and rebellion ahead, when she has an enormous fragility that she does not accept. In the end, she uses this part as a superpower, because being deaf gives her the wisdom to read lips, something that no one expects, not even her greatest enemies," Ortega concluded.
>
> https://www.excelsior.com.mx/funcion/aventura-intriga-y-suspenso-en-el-internado-las-cumbres/1433369

> Amaia also has a hearing disability that could give her an advantage in the intense coexistence she faces.
>
> Yes, the limitation of deafness accompanies Amaia all the time and I think that for her it is a double-edged sword, let's say that it is her fragility that makes her a little vulnerable and where she has the help of Paul (Albert Salazar) and other colleagues. And it's okay to tell these stories. Still, for Amaia she's like a superpower, because she can suddenly read lips. This allows her to have the ability to know more than her enemies may believe.
>
> https://larepublica.pe/espectaculos/2021/02/17/el-internado-las-cumbres-sus-protagonistas

Comment: The interview is an interesting find. I'm not sure about the value of having the original (foreign-language) quotes taking up half your answer if you're just going to translate them anyway.

Comment: I am wondering how can she speak despite she is deaf but I do not see her signing when she had the TV interview. When I watch that show, she is speaking and she does not sign...My guess her speaking is very clear and understanding ?